# AIR application crashes when changing stage displayState to fullscreen

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, air, flashdevelop

A problem started cropping up in my game that hasn't happened before. I have a fullscreen toggle button, and when I press it my game attempts to go into fullscreen but the entire app closes after a few seconds of freezing. No errors are traced when the game closes. I can resize the game just fine (for example the maximize button works as intended), it's just fullscreen that freezes.

I tested the code as shown below:

```
trace("Before fullscreen");
stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN_INTERACTIVE;
trace("After fullscreen");
```

Only "Before fullscreen" is traced out, meaning the displayState change freezes the program. Changing the state to `NORMAL` does not freeze the program, but both `FULL_SCREEN` and `FULL_SCREEN_INTERACTIVE` do. The only other information I could find was someone else having the same problem and discovering graphics card problems, but I haven't done anything to change my graphics settings/drivers so I'm not sure if that's the actual problem here.

Comment: One fix I just discovered was changing the AIR version my game is using. I'm currently on 28, I changed it to 27 and it still crashes, but 26 makes the game go fullscreen with no problems. So perhaps it's a problem with AIR itself. (I should have also checked the current AIR version because I'm horribly out of date)

Comment: AIR 26 uses a different DirectX version. That might be the culprit.